# How to overwrite focus() in JavaScript for all elements?

Tags: javascript

I want to overwrite the function `focus()` for all HTML elements in JavaScript.

How do I do that?

Comment: use a dom inspector to display the dom tree, then use a black sharpie marker to cover up all the onfocus taks on your screen?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What new functionality you would be over-riding?

Comment: @mtk I am including a script which call .focus() which has sideeffects that I don't want. So I want to override that function and replace it with an empty function.

Comment: I would suggest copying and fixing the included script so it doesn't do things you don't want.

Comment: Here's a demo where one particular element's .focus() method has been overriden: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/S6Rm8/.  If you know the target elements, you can apply this override to just those elements.  I would not suggest doing this to every element on the page.

Comment: I found a solution to work around my problem without overwriting focus(). However, the basic question on how to override the function for all elements remains, which I find quite interesting.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't have access to the script and it keeps changing. So, no way fixing the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question asks for just how to override the `.focus()` *method* for HTML elements, so that will be answered first. There are however, other ways to trigger "focus" on elements, and overriding those methods are discussed below.

Please also note, **it is probably not a good idea to override global prototypes**.

---

## Overriding the `.focus()` method on HTML elements

You can override the focus function for all `HTMLElement`'s by modifying its prototype.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.focus = function () {
  // ... do your custom stuff here
}
```

If you still want to run the default focus behavior and run your custom override, you can do the following:

```
let oldHTMLFocus = HTMLElement.prototype.focus;
HTMLElement.prototype.focus = function () {
    // your custom code
    oldHTMLFocus.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

---

## Overriding the focus event set via handlers on HTML elements

This is done in a similar fashion to overriding the `.focus()` method. However, in this case, we will target the `EventTarget` constructor and modify the `addEventListener` prototype:

```
let oldAddListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function () {
    let scope = this;
    let func = arguments[1];

    if (arguments[0] === 'focus') {
        arguments[1] = function (e) {
            yourCustomFunction(scope);
            func(e);
        };
    }

    oldAddListener.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

If you don't want original behavior at all, you can remove the `func` call (`func(e)`).

---

## Overriding the focus event set via the `onfocus` attribute

Doing this is actually quite tricky, and will most likely have some unforseen limitations. That said, I could not find a way to override this by modifying prototypes, etc. The only way I could get this work was by using [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It works by finding all elements that have the attribute `onfocus` and it sets the first function to run to your override function:

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(handleOnFocusElements);
let observerConfig = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeFilter: ['onfocus']
};
let targetNode = document.body;

observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);

function handleOnFocusElements() {
    Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll('[onfocus]:not([onfocus*="yourCustomFunction"])'))
        .forEach(element => {
            let currentCallbacks = element.getAttribute('onfocus');
            element.setAttribute('onfocus', `yourCustomFunction(this); return; ${currentCallbacks}`);
        });
}
```

If you want to stop the original onfocus from firing its events completely, you can just empty the onfocus attribute entirely on any mutation changes, and just set the value to your desired function.

---

## An example with all of the code snippets together:

```js
(function() {

  window.yourCustomFunction = function(target) {
    console.log('OVERRIDE on element', target);
  };

  let observer = new MutationObserver(handleOnFocusElements);

  let observerConfig = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeFilter: ['onfocus']
  };

  let targetNode = document.body;

  // Start overriding methods
  // The HTML `.focus()` method
  let oldHTMLFocus = HTMLElement.prototype.focus;
  HTMLElement.prototype.focus = function() {
    yourCustomFunction(this);
    oldHTMLFocus.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  // Event Target's .addEventListener prototype
  let oldAddListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
  EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function() {
    let scope = this;
    let func = arguments[1];

    if (arguments[0] === 'focus') {
      arguments[1] = function(e) {
        yourCustomFunction(scope);
        func(e);
      };
    }

    oldAddListener.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  // Handle the onfocus attributes
  function handleOnFocusElements() {
    Array
      .from(document.querySelectorAll('[onfocus]:not([onfocus*="yourCustomFunction"])'))
      .forEach(element => {
        let currentCallbacks = element.getAttribute('onfocus');
        element.setAttribute('onfocus', `yourCustomFunction(this); return; ${currentCallbacks}`);
      });
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    handleOnFocusElements();
    observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);
  });
})();

let input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  console.log('Add Event Listener Focus');
});

function attributeHandler() {
  console.log('Called From the Attribute Handler');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="attributeHandler()">
```

Comment: It wouldn't handle when focused trough keyboard or mouse click. Any workaround for it?

Comment: @Binyamin, yep, there are workarounds, although the workaround for overriding attribute driven events (`onfocus`) are more difficult to control. I went ahead and added a couple more ways that the focus event could be overridden.

Comment: @KevBot, after lots of investigation, the only way to change/handle "focus" behavior is by using `document.addEventListener("focus", callback, true)`

Comment: @KevBot, your suggestion with **MutationObserver** is wrong, since it will apply only for fields having attribute "onfocus". Try `document.addEventListener("focus", function(){ document.activeElement.focus(); }, true)` ;) , it will cover any focusable element without dependencies.

Comment: @Binyamin, yeah I went down the route of your suggestion, and while that does capture all focus events, it captures all focus events on elements that never had a listener attached to them. I guess in my answer I was going for overriding those events on an element basis, not a global basis. Thoughts?

Answer (score -2):

In pure JS:

HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="textfield" />​
```

JS:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("test");
myInput.addEventListener("focus",deFocus(myInput),true);

function deFocus(element) {
    element.setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
    return false;
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KG58e/)

In JQuery:

HTML

```
​<input id="test" type="textfield" />
```

JQuery

```
​$('#test').focus(function() {
    $(this).blur();
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZQ9k/)

You can add the `EventListener` to whatever you want, class, id, etc. and run it through the function or trigger something else to unlock them. JQuery can also handle this pretty smoothly, though if you're going that route I would suggest using a class as a selector and then you can add and remove the class dynamically to disable focus.

Comment: then use `$('input').focus()`

Comment: No. "ALL Elements". Not "All input elements" :-). Something like `$('*').focus()` but I doubt that'd work.